# Infinite each() loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few separate headings:

```
<h3 class="ads">First</h3>

<h3 class="ads">Second</h3>

<h3 class="ads">Third</h3>
```

And I'd like to be able to continuously loop over them, changing the text from black to red, and then back to black once the next heading has changed to red.

Here's what I have so far: it works once, however I cannot get it to re-loop succesfully:

```
$('.ads').each(function(i) { 
    var el=$(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.prevAll('.ads').css('color','black');
        el.css('color', 'red');
    }, i * 3000); 
});
```

I'd like to be able to manually set how long I wait in between each change, so an explanation would help a lot too!

[**Here's the jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gNrMJ/)

Comment: use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` for starters maybe.

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Er, why?

Comment: Sorry, don't you want it to keep going? Maybe I misunderstood. Never mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/gNrMJ/21/)

```
var $headings = $('.ads'),
    $length = $headings.length,
    i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $headings.css('color','black');
    $headings.eq(i).css('color', 'red');
    i = (i + 1) % $length;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: `$($headings.get(i))` mein got... Use `$headings.eq(i)` instead.

Comment: Sorry but what language is this?

Comment: It is and I've updated it because it is a good suggestion. But "mein got" doesn't look like English.

Answer (score 4):

You can use recursion to do this elegantly.

```
// configure the delay
var delay = 1000;

// save a pointer to the first element
var first = $('.ads').first();

// this function does the following
// a. color the current element red
// b. make all siblings black
// c. call itself with the next applicable element
function change(_elem) {
    _elem.css('color','red').siblings().css('color', 'black');
    setTimeout(function() {
        change((_elem.next().length > 0) ? _elem.next() : first);
    }, delay);
}

// start if off
change(first);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gNrMJ/16/